# I am new to coding, I don't understand this error message

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I am not sure if my question is valid here...
Hello, so I am Freshman who got involved in some research where we use RStudio to use this program called xROI. The use of coding should have stayed on the minimal level, but right now I am having trouble with xROI, and RStudio says that the error is the following:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7609
Error in matrix(unlist(lsplit[wfilter]), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  [No stack trace available]
Error in (function (x)  : attempt to apply non-function
Called from: (function (x) 
x$.self$finalize())(<environment>)
Error during wrapup: unimplemented type (29) in 'eval'

Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error during wrapup: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29'
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

xROI is used to observe changes over time on a set of given images (meant to be used in plants), and as of right now xROI can't go over the stage in which I pick my area of interest. The message I receive is "Raster is being Produced"

Does anyone have a clue as to what does the error message indicate..?

Comment: I removed the [tag:rstudio] tag because this is about the R programming language and its error, nothing to do with the RStudio IDE. While the StackExchange tag-recommendation engine likely suggested it, please don't blindly accept tags.

Comment: This error is saying that `unlist(lsplit[wfilter])` is returning a `NULL`, not something that can be coerced into a matrix. Check your previous code to find out if `wfilter` is appropriate and non-empty, and if it can be found within `lsplit`.